# Chips click event

Tags: javascript, html

I got multiple chips with the same  class name. I would like to write a javascript that would remove the chips that i clicked on. Here's my code

HTML:

```
<div class = "chips">
 <span>General</span>
 <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>

<div class = "chips">
 <span>test</span>
 <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("body").on("click",".chips .icon-close", function(){
    $(".chips").focus().remove();
});
```

I want the click function to be on the class (".chips .icon-close"). My code currently remove both chips when i click on either one of it

Comment: Something like `$(this).parent('.chips').remove()` in the listener

Answer (score 0):

You can `hide` or `remove` html tag by following code.

```
$("body").on("click",".chips .icon-close", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    //Or hide chips 
     $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$('.chips').click(function(){
    $(this).focus().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "chips">
 <span>General</span>
 <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>

<div class = "chips">
 <span>test</span>
 <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>
```